# Is it possible to clone a repository in lite mode to save disk space?

Tags: git

I want to clone this repository, but it is a huge repo that takes up 1 GB on my hard drive.

Is there a 'lite' way to clone a repository where it doesn't store historical information and full-history?

Answer (score 3):

you can specify clone depth by --depth option of `git clone`

```
 --depth <depth>
       Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the 
       specified number of revisions. A shallow repository has
       a number of limitations (you cannot clone or fetch from
       it, nor push from nor into it), but is adequate if
       you are only interested in the recent history of a large 
       project with a long history, and would want to send in 
      fixes as patches.
```